# Highcharts - Line graph data being skewed by break in data

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've got a line chart that is graphing multiple days worth of data from a csv file. The data is retrieved and set correctly but it's not appearing that way in the Graph.

There's a break in the data and the lines are thrown off.

[image]

I think this may be because the breaks correlate to the change in day. The break in data does not cause a problem for other graphs that use this.

Is this a bug in `Highcharts v4.2.5` or is there something I'm missing?

[image]
[image]

Comment: What does the .csv look like?

Comment: @vsharper it's too long to post. I'll put an example

Comment: Looks to me like your data is not sorted by date.

Comment: @wergeld looks like you're correct. Now I have to find out how to sort a JavaScript  JSON object

Comment: @BarryDale2014 : You could use Underscore.js library if you are planning to modify JSON object frequently. It is easy and simple.

Comment: We need to see some data at least. Better if you also post your code

Comment: Besides your data sorting issue, have you looked into the `connectNulls` attribute? http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.line.connectNulls

Comment: @brightmatrix that doesn't explain the massive line connecting two unrelated points

Comment: @BarryDale2014 That's true, however, I thought it fair to mention this all the same for any gap issues you may have in this or other charts.